# Ethereum-Wallet Unable to connect to node, see the logs for more details

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, synchronization

Previously I had the official windows desktop ethereum-wallet synced and working, but the other day my computer crashed and corrupted my blockchain sync, so I deleted my chaindata folder and started over.  This time I synced with `geth --fast --cache=2048`.  When it was caught up I closed geth and attempted to open the wallet, but ever since then I immediately get an error that says something like "Unable to connect to node, see the logs for more details."  I made sure I was allowing geth to communicate through my firewall, but that didn't fix anything.

My question is, where are the logs and how can I view them? Also when running `geth --fast`, what is the proper way to close geth once it is caught up? I used CTRL-C in the command prompt because I couldn't figure out a better way.  And for future reference, can `geth --fast` be stopped before it's caught up and then resumed later?

Answer (score 2):

`geth --fast` has nothing to do with the connection to node, `--fast` is only telling `geth` to sync the block headers only and enough to perform transactions. A few latest blocks.

#### Wait until the node is fully synced.

> --fast Enables fast syncing through state downloads

Comment: Any idea what could be preventing the node connection?

Comment: @DanielE ipc might be disabled?